# How do i specify my listbox so that VBA understands what I'm referring to?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a macro I wrote for Excel for removing and revealing lines using a Listbox, and it isn't working. I'm getting *Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)* on line 4 of the code. When I was fiddling around previously it often told me that it couldn't find the object, so I'm guessing that I'm doing some kind of formatting error that doesn't let it find the object, but I haven't been able to find what.

I have very little experience with VBA so I might be making some obvious error, but I would really appreciate some help.

```
Sub HideShowLine()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim i As Integer
   For i = 0 To ActiveSheet.Listbox1.ListCount - 1
    If ActiveSheet.Listbox1.Selected(i) = True Then
      ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagram 1").Activate
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse

etc.
```

Comment: How did you load the list box in discussion? In fact, is it loaded with any value? Then, do you know what you are doing? Are there a chart series loaded? Do you know anything about a list box?

Comment: Should I show you how such an object can be handled? At least, does such a `Listbox1` object exist on the active sheet in discussion?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try understanding the meaning of the next code:

```
Sub defineListBoxObject()
   Dim listB As MSForms.listBox ' declare an object as ActiveX list box
   Dim i As Long
   
   'if an ActiveX list box exists on the active sheet:
   Set listB = ActiveSheet.ListBox1 'here you define the list box object. If it exists!
   listB.Clear                                       'clear the list loaded elements
   listB.list = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC") 'load it with some test items
   
   Debug.Print listB.ListCount    'return the number of loaded items
   Debug.Print listB.Selected(1) 'returns True if the second item is selected. If not, it returns False
   
   If listB.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub 'exit the code in case of no any item loaded
   For i = 0 To listB.ListCount - 1
        Debug.Print listB.list(i), listB.Selected(i) 'returns the elements and True if the element is selected
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! It is however still saying that _Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)_ on line 5 of your code, where you define listB. I have made sure numerous times that the object name is in fact Listbox1, but It's still giving me the error.

Comment: @Adam Kallstenius: If so, are you sure that the list box in discussion is an ActiveX type? Did you rename it as "Listbox1"? I supposed that it is of ActiveX type only because adding such a combo, Excel automatically names it as "Listbobox1". If it is a `Form` type and surely named as you say, please try: `Dim listB As ListBox` `Set listB = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("Listbox3")`. Does it return any error? If yes, I am afraid that you do not know where to look after its name. sorry...

Comment: @Adam Kallstenius: If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: The Listbox is of a form type. I tried adding the code you gave me but I'm still getting the same error. Here are links to images of the full code and workbook.[1](https://imgur.com/rtf2NcQ) [2](https://imgur.com/4UlAgkK)

Comment: @Adam Kallstenius: What should I do in your pictures? I was talking about the workbook. Where is your list box? At least, to see it and its name...